# send iframe with youtube in email body

Tags: php, codeigniter

i want to send some html in email body, but gmail doesn't interpret iframe tag with youtube video. Is it because of security violations or other reasons?

here is my code:

```
    this->load->library('email');       
    $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
    $config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
    $this->email->initialize($config);
        $this->email->from('<email>', 'Alega');
        $this->email->to('<email>'); 
        $this->email->subject('Email Test');
        $this->email->message('<iframe title="YouTube video player" width="480" height="390" src="<url>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');   

            $this->email->send();
```

Comment: Gmail parses your e-mails for youtube links and embeds them.

Comment: most email clients won't allow an iframe tag in an email for security reasons

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because of security, it's the same reason you can't put javascript or anything external other than images in an email either - it can give the email too much 'power'. (You can put stuff there, it wont be displayed). Sadly this means no *reliable* flash support either.

In fact, most email readers will not parse even simple tags or CSS because of lack of support, I actually revert to tables just to make sure that the email looks consistent across all the different email clients out there.

Your best/only option is to just link to the video I'm afraid. As mentioned above, Gmail will parse the Youtube links and actually embed them for people who have it enabled.

Comment: I don't find it all sad that people can't send me email with embedded Flash.

Comment: This is completely not true. I have seen many emails that exactly arrives in my box with image/video/nicely layout, center right corner etc. And my boss always shows me those example. (i almost like to kill him, because its so anonymous info nobody shared).

Comment: Clients like Gmail will embed Youtube videos automatically, but trust me 95% of email clients won't.

Answer (score 0):

Many email servers won't allow this due to security reason. But you can try these following solutions.

Solution 1:

```
    $var = html_escape('<iframe title="YouTube video player" width="480" height="390" src="<url>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
    $this->email->message($var);
```

Solution 2:

```
$this->email->message('<&nbs;iframe title="YouTube video player" width="480" height="390" src="<url>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen><&nbs;/iframe>');
```

However, in solution 2 you need to inform the receiver to remove space from a tag.